# JS async await does not wait and not blocks the process

Tags: javascript

I want to acheive something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   console.log("1");
}, 3000);

console.log("2");
```

And I want 1 to be logged before 2.

I have tried this:

```
async function a() {
  var v = await setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("1");
  }, 3000);
  console.log("2");
}

a();
```

And I have tried more things but nothing works.
How do I tell JS to WAIT until one thing is done, then go to next thing.
Please, WITHOUT THE USE OF PROMISE!

Thanks.

Comment: Wihout the use of promise? But you want to use `async/await`? Huh?

Comment: You can't do it without promises, If the awaited expression isn’t a promise, its casted into a promise.

Comment: await and async can't to  work without promice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to use `await/async` without promises. The whole functionality is based on promises. Sometimes it may seem like it works without promises, but that's only because some other function is returning a promise.

The best you can do is create a simple wait function that returns the promise and `await` it. For example:

```js
wait =  (time) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))

async function test(){
    console.log("one")
    // Pause
    await wait(2000)
    // continue
    console.log("two")
}

test()
```

There is nothing (that you should be using) in javascript that will suspend the event loop and wait. Part of writing JS is learning to work with this fact.

Comment: You can use await with promises, or with whatever: `async function() { let c = await 1; return c }`, in the op's example the value that await is `timeoutId` (what setTimeout returns)

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Of course you can await a synchronous return - but that's not what the OP wants. If you can do this please add an answer showing how to do what the OP is asking without using promises.

Comment: I think I can't. XD I was only pointing the behaviour that happens in OP example. (Await for synchronous value). Of course if you want to await for asynchronous, the expression should be a promise. It was just for clarify.

Comment: Thanks. I thought async differ from promises, I just want to do actions after the callback from HTTP request..

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because `setTimeout` doesn't return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). Here's a little helper function that actually returns a Promise and achieves what you wanted to do:

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

Use it like this:

```
async function a() {
  await sleep(3000);
  console.log("1");
  console.log("2");
}

a();
```

This waits for 3000 milliseconds, logs `"1"` and then `"2"`. I don't get why you would need to wait before something happens, but I just "translated" your code to actually use Promises.

Comment: I do not need to wait, the setTimeout function is just a for example, actually I demonstrate something that takes time, like HTTP request to a remote server, only after it back, I want to do another thing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just use a Promise-compatible HTTP library like [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native).